# jquery dataTable reset sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I am trying to do a task, just as same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839241/reset-to-default-sorting-in-jquery-datatable).

- I have a working jquery dataTable
- I want a function to reset the sorting, which is before user select any column, same as read in from the HTML.

It lead me to a nice plugin.

http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnSortNeutral

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnSortNeutral = function ( oSettings )
{
    /* Remove any current sorting */
    oSettings.aaSorting = [];

    /* Sort display arrays so we get them in numerical order */
    oSettings.aiDisplay.sort( function (x,y) {
        return x-y;
    } );
    oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.sort( function (x,y) {
        return x-y;
    } );

    /* Redraw */
    oSettings.oApi._fnReDraw( oSettings );
};
```

However I dont know "How to make it work". Anyone know what is "oApi", or do I need some more setup before I use this plugin ?

Because my script shows up `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oApi' of undefined` , right after I copy the script, and the error makes the function undefined. What should I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a usage example in the link you provided.

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable();

// Sort in the order that was originally in the HTML
table.fnSortNeutral();
```

**EDIT** Try giving it an "order" property when initializing: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cohiha/1/edit?console,output)

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnSortNeutral = function ( oSettings )
{
    /* Remove any current sorting */
    oSettings.aaSorting = [];

    /* Sort display arrays so we get them in numerical order */
    oSettings.aiDisplay.sort( function (x,y) {
        return x-y;
    } );
    oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.sort( function (x,y) {
        return x-y;
    } );

    /* Redraw */
    oSettings.oApi._fnReDraw( oSettings );
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "order" : [[ 1, "desc" ]]
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        oTable.fnSortNeutral()
    }, 1000)

});
```

Comment: yes, I have try this one.
But before the line `table.fnSortNeutral();` run, the plugin script itself has a error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oApi' of undefined`, so it can not run.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. For me it is better to using `aaSorting:[]` property, and I put a button to run the reset sorting function. Here's the edited usage for other who like to refence : 
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bezudiyawu/4/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 7):

For DataTable **1.10+** can be used [order.neutral()](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/order.neutral()) plugin

**PLUGIN CODE**

```js
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'order.neutral()', function () {
    return this.iterator( 'table', function ( s ) {
        s.aaSorting.length = 0;
        s.aiDisplay.sort( function (a,b) {
            return a-b;
        } );
        s.aiDisplayMaster.sort( function (a,b) {
            return a-b;
        } );
    } );
} );
```

**CDN:** [cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/api/order.neutral().js](https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/api/order.neutral().js)

**EXAMPLE**

```js
// Return table to the loaded data order
  table.order.neutral().draw();
```